# Can private objects in parent class be inherited by sub class using super keyword

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, super

I wanted to ask if it is possible if private objects of my parent class can be inherited by my subclass through the super keyword.

I ask because I have a task for school, and I thought that private objects cannot be inherited. I also receive an error in my code and I struggle to find anything online to help me with this specifically.

For example, my parent class has:

```
public class Person {
private String firstName;
```

And then in my sub class I have:

```
public class Lecturer extends Person {
//....

super.firstName = firstName;
```

NetBeans gives me the warning that 'firstName has private access'.

Comment: So NetBeans have already given you the answer or what exactly is it you are asking about?

Comment: Can private objects in parent class be inherited by sub class using super keyword? NO. Private means private, i.e. they belong only to the class, not to other classes, including subclasses

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do something like this

Person class:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Subclass in separate file:

```
public class Employee extends Person {

    public Employee(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public void test() {
        System.out.println("getName = " + getName()); // works
        // can also do super, although it's not necessary
        System.out.println("getName = " + super.getName());
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use super.method(), but super.variable then you need to change the name variable to not be private but package-private by removing the "private" from its declaration:

```
public class Person {

    String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Employee

```
public class Employee extends Person {
    public Employee(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public void test() {
        System.out.println("this.name = " + name);
    }
}
```

My previous answer used an inner class but that shouldn't be used as it would be a misuse of inner classes.

Comment: You would need to declare `Employee` in your first example as `public static class Employee`, otherwise it is an innerclass that requires an instance of `Person`, instead of a nested class.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thank you, you are right. It would also have been a misuse of inner classes.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no, they cannot be inherited.

Private variables cannot be reached from anywhere but the declaring class. This means that your `super.firstName = firstName` actually has 2 errors: super.firstName cannot be accessed since its private, and the firstName field does not exists from the subclass's point of view.

The only way of accessing a private variable or method directly is via reflection, and even then you have to use the setAccessible(boolean) method which might be prevented by SecurityManagers.

If you have a setter (or parameterized constructor) which accesses the private variable you can use it from an other class (due to the method being public).